# ERROR 1241 Operand should contain 1 column Subquery weekday

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to perform a mysql query that shows the amount of products that have been made during this week, from Monday to Sunday.(In the code only Lunes and Martes in this example)

I have managed to perform the query with a single id, but when I want to show everyone it gives me error.

```
select formatopeso.tipo_formato, (select sum(cantidad) 
from previsionpedidos 
where id_formatopeso = 1 and  WEEKDAY(fecha) = 0) as Lunes, 
(select sum(cantidad) fromprevisionpedidos where id_formatopeso = 1 and  WEEKDAY(fecha) = 1) 
as Martes, 
from previsionpedidos inner join formatopeso on 
previsionpedidos.id_formatopeso = formatopeso.id_formatopeso 
where formatopeso.id_formatopeso= 1 and yearweek(fecha,1) = yearweek(now()) 
group by formatopeso.tipo_formato;
```

I try this, but I have a error ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
select formatopeso.tipo_formato,
(select sum(cantidad) from previsionpedidos inner join 
formatopeso on previsionpedidos.id_formatopeso = formatopeso.id_formatopeso 
where WEEKDAY(fecha) = 0) as lunes,
(select sum(cantidad),fecha from previsionpedidos 
inner join formatopeso on previsionpedidos.id_formatopeso = 
formatopeso.id_formatopeso
where WEEKDAY(fecha) = 1) as Martes from previsionpedidos 
inner join formatopeso on previsionpedidos.id_formatopeso = formatopeso.id_formatopeso 
where yearweek(fecha,1) = yearweek(now()) 
group by formatopeso.tipo_formato;
```

Thanks

I need show result similar to:

```
+--------------+-------+--------+
| tipo_formato | Lunes | Martes |
+--------------+-------+--------+
| 12Ø 70gr     |   175 |   250  |
| 20Ø 150gr    |   NULL|   NULL |
| 22Ø 180gr    |   NULL|   125  |
| 25Ø 220gr    |   200 |   NULL |
| 28Ø 220gr    |   175 |   250  |
+--------------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an excess comma before `FROM`.

```
SELECT formatopeso.tipo_formato, 
    (SELECT SUM(cantidad) 
     FROM previsionpedidos 
     WHERE id_formatopeso = 1 
        AND  WEEKDAY(fecha) = 0
    ) as Lunes, 
    (SELECT SUM(cantidad) 
    FROM previsionpedidos 
    WHERE id_formatopeso = 1 
        AND WEEKDAY(fecha) = 1
    ) as Martes 
FROM previsionpedidos 
INNER JOIN formatopeso on previsionpedidos.id_formatopeso = formatopeso.id_formatopeso 
WHERE formatopeso.id_formatopeso=1 
    AND yearweek(fecha,1) = yearweek(now()) 
GROUP BY formatopeso.tipo_formato;
```

Comment: 193/5000
Thanks for the help friend, that has solved that the code is cleaner and tidier, but my request is going to be able to show all the products with his id and I can only show one